# Pandas Multiple Dataframe Join Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I've got 20 dataframes, at the final stage i want to merge all of them by following code piece:

```
finalDF=allDf[0]
for df in allDf[1:]:
   finalDf=finalDF.join(df, on='DateTime')
```

which gives memory error. are there any memory-wise better way of combining dataframes?

Each dataframe has numeric 20 columns and each of them ranges from 2015-01-01 to current date, having unique/distinct datetimes.

Comment: Is the 'Datetime' column unique for all the dataframes in your list? If not you are could be creating a huge Cartesian product that no computer would have enough memory for. Also, how wide are each of your dataframes? If you only need one column from the joining dataframe make sure you shrink your dataframes column wise first.

Comment: Please show some data as example and the specific error with traceback.

Comment: @TedPetrou yes they are unique, each df has like 20 columns

Comment: @Parfait Each dataframe has numeric 20 columns and each of them ranges from 2015-01-01 to current date, having unique/distinct datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
finalDF = pd.concat([d.set_index('DateTime') for d in allDF], axis=1)
```